# Push able connection between two Node Servers

Tags: node.js

Best Solution for a pushable connection between two node server ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pushable connection"?

Comment: both sides can push messages, like a websocket connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sockets](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/net.html#net.Socket) offers full-duplex communication. You should checkout [this](http://vimeo.com/18077379) video presentation where this functionality is demonstrated (it starts around 20:15).